# Athena - How to query by nested json value?

Tags: json, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-athena

In Athena, we're trying to get all fruits that contain seeds. The issue we're facing is that seeds true/false is nested in json and we can't seem to filter by it in the `WHERE` clause. We can only see results when we `SELECT` it as `hasSeeds` from the nested json path, but that returns all seed results `true` and `false` instead of just `true`

```
-- This returns all seeds, but we want to filter in the WHERE clause by hasSeeds true
SELECT foodId, foodType, json_extract(payload,'$.food.info.seeds') AS hasSeeds
FROM "food_table"
WHERE foodType = 'fruit'

-- 3 attempts to filter by nested json value seeds true (not working)
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT foodId, foodType, json_extract(payload,'$.food.info.seeds') AS hasSeeds
FROM "food_table"
WHERE foodType = 'fruit')
WHERE hasSeeds = true

SELECT foodId, foodType, json_extract(payload,'$.food.info.seeds') AS hasSeeds
FROM "food_table"
WHERE foodType = 'fruit' and hasSeeds = true

SELECT foodId, foodType, json_extract(payload,'$.food.info.seeds') AS hasSeeds
FROM "food_table"
WHERE foodType = 'fruit' and json_extract(payload,'$.food.info.seeds') = true
```

Any idea how we can get the query to work as expected where we filter by `hasSeeds` true on the nested json?

Update with JSON structure:

```
{
  "foodId": 1,
  "foodType": "fruit",
  "payload": {
    "food": {
      "name": "apple",
      "info": {
        "seeds": true,
        "calories": 95
      }
    }
  }
}

{
  "foodId": 2,
  "foodType": "fruit",
  "payload": {
    "food": {
      "name": "banana"
    }
  }
}

{
  "foodId": 3,
  "foodType": "vegetable",
  "payload": {
  }
}

{
  "foodId": 4,
  "foodType": "fruit",
  "payload": {
  }
}
```

Tried this query but it returns incorrect results:

```
WITH dataset(jsn) AS (
    values (JSON '{"payload":{"food":{"info":{"seeds":true}}}}')
)

SELECT foodId, foodType, json_extract(payload,'$.food.info.seeds') AS hasSeeds, jsn
FROM "food_table", dataset
WHERE cast(json_extract_scalar(jsn, '$.payload.food.info.seeds') AS BOOLEAN) = true
```

Basically, the `hasSeeds` comes back as true which is correct, but other food items, like those missing a payload's children still comeback with the jsn field, instead of actually just querying only on the `WHERE` clause by something like `payload.food.info.seeds` = `true`

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Can you please share the json example?

Comment: Updated with json example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have next json structure, you need to use `json_extract_scalar`:

```sql
WITH dataset(jsn) AS (
    values (JSON '{"food":{"info":{"seeds":true}}}')
)

SELECT *
FROM dataset
WHERE cast(json_extract_scalar(jsn, '$.food.info.seeds') AS BOOLEAN) = true
```

**UPD**

Based on provided json `WHERE` clause should look something like:

```
WHERE try(cast(json_extract_scalar(payload, '$.payload.food.info.seeds') AS BOOLEAN)) = true
```

Comment: Thanks for jumping in! I added an update as it's not working as expected, do we need to tweak something?

Comment: @BigMike  `with dataset....` is to set up some example data, you should not join with, you should use `json_extract_scalar` on your data. i.e `WHERE cast(json_extract_scalar(payload, '$.payload.food.info.seeds') AS BOOLEAN) = true`

Comment: @BigMike since not every payload has data you need to wrap the `json_extract_scalar` into `try`

Comment: hmm.. but the data is in the "food_table" db table, so we can't query on it you mean?

Comment: @BigMike you should query your data. `dataset` is MY example data with json field which I use to show how to extract boolean `seeds` value.